# jQuery Ajax not failing after unauthorised post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a jQuery .Ajax post type JSON and an MVC controller with an [Authorise] attribute.
on the return jQuery carries out "success" if user is authorized, but never carries out the "fail". how to handle when user is not authorized?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/index",
  dataType: "json",
  data: { ID: id, Name: name },
  success: function(data){...},
  fail: function(){...}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/index",
  dataType: "json",
  data: { ID: id, Name: name },
  success: function(data){...},
  error: function(){...}
});
```

Here's a similar post: [json-parameters-auto-convert-to-lowercase-when-ajax-request-made-to-mvc-action-m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377071/json-parameters-auto-convert-to-lowercase-when-ajax-request-made-to-mvc-action-m)

Answer (score 4):

error: not fail:

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options

Check out the request in firebug to see the request in real time, will make your life much, much easier